# mails are not getting sent using xampp but the mail content is stored as text format in mailoutput folder

Tags: php, email, xampp

PHP script

```
$from = "xyz@gmail.com";
$to = "xyz@yahoo.com";
$subject = "subject";
$mailtext = "blablabla";
if (mail($to, $subject, $mailtext, "From: $from "))    
{    
  echo "Enquiry sent!";    
}else {
  echo "fail!";    
}
```

When I run the code it displays enquiry sent which means mail is sent but the mail is not recieved .

Comment: Most likely this is because you are on a localhost and without configuring a mail server or using something like phpmailer or another lib you won't be able to send out mails.

Comment: Can you please share the configuration or any details on the same because i have already done the configurations in the localhost sendmail.ini and php.ini

Comment: php's sendmail isn't a mail server, you either need to install a mail server (as mentioned before) or use something similar to phpmailer (google it).

Answer (score 0):

Cause you can not send email from localhost. It stored as text file to simulate sending email .

Comment: Is there any freeware application to send the mail.Because i tried postcast server it didnt work